# When performing a 3-step analysis in Latent Gold, should I use ML or BCH to model an ordinal outcome?

Tags: ordered-logit, latent-class

I'm performing a 3-step analysis in Latent Gold 5.1. In step 3 I estimate a model with an ordinal distant outcome. The documentation of Latent Gold gives advice for when to use ML (categorical dependent) or BCH (continuous and count dependent). But it does not explicitly state which method to use when modelling an ordinal dependent variable. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question, based on the kind advice of Prof. Vermunt: for ordinal dependent variables in a 3-step LCA, ML is adviced.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).